# List all atributes of a class

Tags: python

We can list all atributes(only atributes) of a class?

If we have, this class for example:

```
class c1():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.fx = x
        self.fy = y
        self.fz = 0

    def fun1():
        return self.fx
```

With dir(c1) we get a full list with all objects of class, including atributes, however we can`t know the diference of methods and atributes.

I was think that will works:

`type( dir(obj1)[-1] )` # [-1] Would be the last attribute, but the type return a string.

Comment: I copy/pasted the title of your question into google and it was the second result. `c1().__dict__.keys()` (you need to create an instance of your class).

Comment: Methods *are* attributes; they just happen to be callable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`__dict__`](https://codesachin.wordpress.com/2016/06/09/the-magic-behind-attribute-access-in-python/) keyword to access attributes.

```
class c1():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.fx = x
        self.fy = y
        self.fz = 0

    def fun1():
        return self.fx

obj1 = c1(1,2)
print(obj1.__dict__)
```

Output

> {'fx': 1, 'fy': 2, 'fz': 0}

Answer (score 2):

Use `__dict__.keys()`:

```py
class c1():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.fx = x
        self.fy = y
        self.fz = 0

    def fun1():
        return self.fx

obj1 = c1(1,2)
print(obj1.__dict__.keys())
```

Output: `dict_keys(['fx', 'fy', 'fz'])`

You might also want to look at [pprint()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)